# Split string based on whitespace and add it to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I need a function that takes in a string, and creates a new list every time there are two whitespace characters.

my_text = '101\n102\n103\n\n111\n112\n113\n'

I want to create a new list each time there's two whitespace characters.

[101, 102, 103]
[111, 112, 113]

I've tried:

```
def my_list(*args, end='\n\n'):
    for arg in args:
       new_list = []
       if end:
          new_list.append(arg)
    print(new_list)
```

but that just adds all the numbers to a single list.

Comment: I highly doubt your program adds anything to anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the split() method to split the string on the '\n\n' and '\n' delimiter

```
my_text_parts = my_text.split('\n\n')

for text_part in my_text_parts:
    numbers = text_part.split('\n')

    new_list = []
    for number in numbers:
        new_list.append(int(number))

 print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append to the final entry in the list, when you get an empty line, add a new empty list.  I assume here that you're passing in the whole string.  Your `*args` thing doesn't make much sense, but you didn't show us how it would be called.

```
def my_list(text):
    result = [[]]
    for arg in text.split('\n'):
        if not arg:
            result.append([])
        else:
            result[-1].append(int(arg))
    result.pop()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
def create_lists(my_text):
    # Split the string into a list of substrings by two '\n' characters
    substrings = my_text.rstrip().split('\n\n')

    # Create a list of lists by splitting each substring by '\n' characters
    lists = [substring.split('\n') for substring in substrings]

    # Convert the list of lists to a list of lists of integers
    lists = [[int(x) for x in lst] for lst in lists]

    # Return the list of lists
    return lists
```

In this function, we first split the input string into a list of substrings by two \n characters using the split() method. Then, we create a list of lists by splitting each substring by \n characters using a list comprehension.

Next, we convert the list of lists to a list of lists of integers by using a nested list comprehension that converts each string element in the list to an integer using the int() function. Finally, we return the list of lists of integers.

You can test the function using the following code:

```py
my_text = '101\n102\n103\n\n111\n112\n113\n'

lists = create_lists(my_text)

print(lists)

[[101, 102, 103], [111, 112, 113]]
```